# How to use Taylor series to find the value of the limit

Tags: calculus

Find the limit of the following function:
$\tan(x)^{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}$, when $x$ is approaching $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
I think Taylor series should help, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: **hint** define $x=\frac \pi 2 -y$ and work around $y=0$. May be, think about logarithms